# I am getting two projects source under "Source control navigator" in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, git

In my Xcode I can see two projects source "**Source control navigator**" option as below,
[image]

And so if I make commits from Xcode I am getting the changes list in both the projects.

**Note**:

1. I am using source tree for GIT operations,
2. I have tried removing and adding the project freshly again the same issue occurs,
3. In source tree only one project is shown and no issue in that.
4. But in the "**Project navigator**" I am seeing only one project as shown below.
   [image]

I want to know what could be the issue and why this occurs and how to rectify it?

Answer (score 8):

Here it is. I hope this will help.
[Xcode 9 – Source Control Navigator issue](http://ubunifu.co/development/xcode-9-source-control-navigator-issue)

Comment: Big help !! Thank you

Comment: Just wanted to add - in addition to deleting the line in the project.pbxproj file, you also need to delete that project's derived data else the extra source code tree will pop up again

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by moving the project folder to new directory. For me it is happening because I try to duplicate the project and add new git from the current committed.